# How can I have a composite key in Kotlin?

Tags: dictionary, kotlin

In Python i can have complex dictionary keys like for example:

```
d = {}
d[(1, 2)] = 3
print d[(1, 2)]  # prints 3
```

How can I declare and populate such a Map in Kotlin?

Edit: I tried to declare a Map like this, but I don't know how to populate it:

```
val my_map = HashMap<Pair<Int, Int>, Int>()
```

Comment: It's not inherently more complex. The key can be any type you like, including a pair.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's simple, you first create your dictionary and then insert the key and values:

```
val (a, b):Pair<Int, String> = Pair(1, "x")

val map: HashMap<Pair<Int, String>, Int> = hashMapOf((a, b) to 1)

map[Pair(2, "y")] = 3
```

and so on :)

Comment: Ok it worked, i had to explicitly write "Pair" like this: `my_map[Pair(1, 2)] = 3`

Comment: @fafl great! Yes once you created, you also can add element like that way, I have always loved to help.

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin, unlike Python there's no tuple data type. For two-tuples there's a Pair class. For larger arity you are supposed to use data classes.

```
val map: HashMap<Pair<Int, Int>, Int> = hashMapOf(Pair(1, 2) to 3)
val nullable: Int? = map[Pair(1, 2)]
val notNullable = map.getValue(Pair(1, 2))
```

Comment: Larger than `Pair` you have `Triple`. For 4-element tuples and beyond, yes, data classes.

Answer (score 1):

## Set

You can use set

`val my_map = mutableMapOf<Set<Int>,Int>()`

or

`val my_map = mutableMapOf<Set<Any>,Int>()`

and use it

`my_map[setOf(1,2)] = 5`